# Gsutil creates 'tmp' files in the buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

We are using automation scripts to upload thousands of files from MAPR HDFS to GCP storage. Sometimes the files in the main bucket appear with `tmp~!@` suffix it causes failures in our pipeline.

> Example:
>
> gs://some_path/.pre-processing/file_name.gz.tmp~!@

We are using `rsync -m` and in certain cases `cp -I`

```
 some_file | gsutil -m cp -I '{GCP_DESTINATION}'

 gsutil -m rsync {MAPR_SOURCE} '{GCP_DESTINATION}'
```

It's possible that copy attempt failed and retried later from a different machine, eventually, we have both the file and another one with the `tmp~!@` suffix

I'd want to get rid of these files without actively looking for them.

we have gsutil 4.33, appreciate any lead. Thx

Comment: Use the `-x pattern` command line option to exclude files. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync

Comment: We can do that, but if such tmp~!@ files are the only ones in the bucket, the gsutil will fail, there is an open issue for that, but meanwhile, it causes a lot of alerts.
If there are no other options we will add filters. thx